# Changing DOM but not appearing in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Using jQuery I am making an ajax call to append data to some input fields, jquery is changing the DOM but the changes are not appearing in the inputs until I click on them.

Here is my jquery code:

```
var data_track = '';
         var data_image = '';
         var data_artist = '';
         var data_album = '';
         var data_duration = '';
         var data_mbid = '';
         if(data.track.name) {data_track = data.track.name;}else{ data_track =  '';}
         if(data.track.album) {data_image = data.track.album.image[3]['#text'];}else{ data_image =  'http://placehold.it/250x250';}
         if(data.track.artist.name) {data_artist = data.track.artist.name;}else{ data_artist =  '';}
         if(data.track.album) {data_album = data.track.album.title;}else{ data_album =  '';}
         if(data.track.duration) {data_duration = data.track.duration;}else{ data_duration =  '';}
         if(data.track.mbid) {data_mbid = data.track.mbid;}else{ data_mbid =  '';}

         $('#track-name').val(data_track);
         $('#image').val(data_image);
         $('#image_preview').attr('src', data_image);
         $('#artist').val(data_artist);
         $('#album').val(data_album);
         $('#duration').val(data_duration);
         $('#mbid').val(data_mbid);
         $('#results').html('');
```

Comment: can you show us tha whole code or maybe a demo on fiddle so we can help you ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another problem this code was inside ajax call and when i scored it `$('#results').html('');`
out of ajax, code working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/b4revvz6/2/
Check your `data` object;